# C#: Как можно упростить конструкцию try-catch?

Tags: c#

Довольно часто приходится в коде использовать `try-catch` при получении каких-либо данных из словаря, в котором этих данных может не быть.

**Обычно делаю так:**

```
int result;
try
{
    // для примера какой-либо индекс и ключ
    result = MyDict[SomethingIndex]["SomethingKey"];
}
catch
{
    result = 0;
}
```

Можно ли как-то уменьшить этот блок кода?

Comment: try-catch довольно затратная операция. Для проверки наличия ключа лучше использовать условие

Comment: Если у вас появился вложенный словарь - значит с архитектурой что-то не так. Но в целом `if (MyDict.TryGetValue(index, out var innerDict) && innerDict.TryGetValue(key, out int result)) { найдено } else { не найдено }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элемент из словаря можно получать через [TryGetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0).
А при условии что это надо делать часто можно для удобства сделать метод расширение.

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int Get(this Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> dictionary, int intKey, string strKey)
    {
        int result = 0;
        dictionary.TryGetValue(intKey, out var innerDictionary);
        innerDictionary?.TryGetValue(strKey, out result);
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var MyDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
        MyDict.Add(1, new Dictionary<string, int>());
        MyDict[1].Add("q", 2);

        var result = MyDict.Get(1, "q");        
    }
}
```

PS: описания MyDict в вопросе нет поэтому исходил что это словарь словарей

Comment: Как отличить 0, вернувшийся из словаря от 0, не найденного в словаре? Кажется это api дает слегка неоднозначный результат.